# Simple Login NSURLConnection

Tags: html, objective-c, forms, authentication

How to perform a simple Log in through textFields in my app to a site like this? 
https://sms12.schoolsoft.se/drottningblanka/jsp/Login.jsp

Really need help with this. Haven´t found anything applicable to me. However it would seem easy to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you can populate this page in UIWebView and perform Login action.

OR

2.create A UI with passord textfield , user name text field.Obtain webs service API for login from your server. the textfields in your screen will give you the username and password , use GET/POST method for login action with these details.

Comment: Is it possible without getting the API from the server since it is not my server? Or can I Obtain this info when logged in?

Comment: I dont think you will get the info , the only thing you can do is implementing webView delegate - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType and check the request (from request you get the url they calling while login)